# Exporting a repository from Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory, sonatype

I have seen that Artifactory provides some useful REST api’s which we can use to interact with the repository itself. I was looking for a specific api call which would enable me to export a particular repository from Artifactory (exporting to a maven repository type). Does Artifactory api provides this option?

Comment: As far as i know only the administrative interface contains a possibility to export a repository to a file system...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, thanks for your info. I have explored this option through the admin panel. But the approach that i was looking for is an automated one, via the api.